# Make HTTP request from Cadence SKILL program?

Tags: rest, http, cadence

Is it possible for Cadence SKILL code to make an HTTP request? If so, how?

I have Googled and read the SKILL manuals I can find with no clear answer. I found [this integration with a Python program](https://community.cadence.com/cadence_technology_forums/f/48/t/20072) which suggests that external programs can be called. If a scripting language (e.g. Python) or HTTP tool (e.g. curl) is installed, it seems a call to an HTTP endpoint / REST API might be possible though that external proxy. I am hoping for something more built-in and less dependent on external helpers and the vagaries of a three-party conversation. Is a direct HTTP request possible? How?

Comment: I suggest you to look into Cadence Inter Process Communication manual. Also, I've implemented a script for that in python, check it here: https://github.com/unnir/CadenceSKILL-Python I believe you can get the idea from there...

Comment: I feared IPC was the best I'd be able to do. It's a reasonable, if slightly indirect, solution. If you make this an answer rather than a comment, I'll mark it as the accepted answer. Either way, thanks!

Comment: let's wait for the real answer :)

Comment: From my reading, guessing this is the best answer available. Have found nothing to suggest there is native REST / web service API capability. Harnessing an external resource via IPC seems to be the only practical avenue.

Comment: one thing more, you can try openaccess https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenAccess, however, if you are not from academia it would cost you a fortune